# The entity type 'bool' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a web application that has a model called "TCategoria". This model has a parameter called "Estado".

The problem is:
I created a try and catch to update "Estado" in data base but appear this error:
The entity type 'bool' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.
I don't understand this error because my parameter "Estado" is a bool.

Model:

```
public class TCategoria
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoriaID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo nombre es obligatorio.")]

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo descripcion es obligatorio.")]

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public bool Estado { get; set; } = true;

    public ICollection<TCursos> Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

Metode, try

```
internal IdentityError UpdateEstado(int id)
    {
        IdentityError identityError;
        try
        {
            var categoria = _context._TCategoria.Where(c => c.CategoriaID.Equals(id)).ToList().ElementAt(0);
            categoria.Estado = categoria.Estado ? false : true;
            _context.Update(categoria.Estado);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            identityError = new IdentityError { Description = "Done" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            identityError = new IdentityError
            {
                Code = "Error",
                Description = e.Message
            };
        }
        return identityError;
    }
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mymgq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should directly update the entity `categoria` :

```
_context.Update(categoria);
```

EF Core will automatically trace the updated property compare to the original values , and update new value in database when calling  `SaveChanges` function .